# png with transparency and png-derived blob are rendering black on canvas element instead of transparent

Tags: php, blob, jcrop

I am letting users preview images using URL.createObjectURL() (which represents the image as a blob). This has worked great, but now I am using the plugin `jCrop` to let users crop said images and I have encountered a minor issue.

jCrop has worked fine for blobs derived from jpg files and png files w/o transparency, but blobs derived from png files with transparency are rendering transparent pixels (on the canvas) as black (the same effect was happening with these images when resized and uploaded to the backend (php) but this was corrected using `imagealphablending()`).

jCrop is called as followed:

```
 jQuery(function($) {
        $("#myImageContainer").Jcrop({
            onChange: myFunction
        }, function () {
            jcrop_api = this;
        });
 });
```

The "black" images on canvas are uploaded and saved properly with transparency, so this is a front end effect only. Additionally, the same effect is observed when the source png is used to preview instead of the png-derived blob. Is their any way to correct for this effect on the canvas instead of the backend?

UPDATE: The transparent image is black from the start...I am assuming the author of the plugin set the canvas background to be black. I will try and change this.

Comment: you need to provide your code code

Comment: We can't diagnose without example image & code, but it sounds like transparent images are sneaking into your process. Transparent pixels are `rgba(0,0,0,0)`. If you force transparent pixels onto a format that doesn't allow transparency (like .jpg), then canvas will just slam the alpha to 255: `rgba(0,0,0,255)`. This causes formerly transparent pixels to become black.

Comment: Setting the canvas CSS *background:black* to black has no effect on `canvas.toDataURL`.

Comment: Not background color...using fillStyle

Comment: Never mind...just went to plugin page and author has an option for this...sorry to waste time

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob. No problem...glad you got it sorted. Be sure you post+accept an answer to your question or delete your question so it doesn't hang around the "unanswered" queue. :-)

Comment: OK..I'm really irked now. The bgColor option shown at: http://www.deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Manual.html does not seem to work when changing to white (or #fff)

Comment: @markE, this library doesn't seem to use the `<canvas>` element.  They don't do cropping, they just send coordinates and the cropping must be done from php side. So if OP wants png, he should use `imagecreatefrompng` on his php page. Removing the canvas tags from this question.